# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed. error while reader is open

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
{
  c = Request.QueryString["city"];
  SqlConnection objConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand objCmd2;
SqlDataReader objRdr2;
//  String strCmd2;
objConn2.Open();

objCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subject_details WHERE Roll_no = " +"'" + c + "'", objConn2);

objRdr2 = objCmd2.ExecuteReader();

while (objRdr2.Read())
{
    Label122.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Name"].ToString().ToUpper();

    objRdr2.Close();
    objConn2.Close();

}
```

This code was working perfectly alright, suddenly I'm getting the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call Read when
>   reader is closed.

Can anyone can help me why am getting this error

Comment: Please use a sql parameter to pass that city. Your code will fail (or worse) if that happens to contain a `'` (sql injection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Close()` should be after `while` loop as below

```
while (objRdr2.Read())
    {
        Label122.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Name"].ToString().ToUpper();
    }

objRdr2.Close();
objConn2.Close();
```

but above code set to `Label122.InnerText` last value from your query. So you should add `TOP 1` to the query

```
objCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1* FROM subject_details WHERE Roll_no = " +
"'" + c + "'", objConn2);
```

then in `Label122.InnerText` will be first value from your query. You can also remove `while` loop as below

```
objRdr2.Read();
Label122.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Name"].ToString().ToUpper();
objRdr2.Close();
objConn2.Close();
```

then in `Label122.InnerText` will be first value from the query too.

Answer (score 2):

you shoudl remove `objRdr2.Close();` from while loop
it should be after while loop

like below

```
while (objRdr2.Read())
    {
        Label122.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Name"].ToString().ToUpper();


        objConn2.Close();

    }

   objRdr2.Close();
```

if you close it inside while loop on next loop the error you specified will throw